# Which Webpart to fetch data from Multiple Columns in Multiple SPS 2013 List?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, content-query-web-part, data-view-web-part, cswp

I want to show specific data from specific columns in Multiple SPS 2013 List.
Based on my research so far, the option to build it revolves around:

a) CQWP
b) CSWP
c) DVWP (Data Vew Webpart)

Looking for community suggestion, to understand which one is better while trying to achieve:

- Non Developer friendly
- Flexibility
- user level ease
- Less development time

Any suggestion will be deeply appreciated.

Jason

Comment: This will not lead to any specific answer, because all the WebParts are good enough to perform its task as per requirement.

Comment: @AakashMorya, I`m back to square one. Please suggest if any other approach to invest time on the appropriate web-part?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add one line that this question seems to be Opinion based. So in my opinion if I have to work with the given requirement I will definitely go with **CSWP**. Because this covers all the above requirement specified.

Because configuring search queries is quite easy job and take less efforts. For me [this](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html) link had a great way to guide **CSWP**.

Want to add some more reflection.

> If the functionality you are creating needs fully up-to-date results
>   (e.g. a user has created/edited something and it needs to be
>   *immediately* reflected in the site) then you will probably need to stick with the original approaches (i.e. a query-based rather than
>   search-based solution).

Answer (score 0):

I do suggest to go with CSWP. The reason is it is very flexible and easy to use, but also very complex and can be customized to do amazing stuff. I know you mentioned that you dont want that much dev time, so I would say invest some time to understand the basics and it has a basic mode where you can just build the query based on drop downs and you don't need that much dev experience. I am sure if you search for resources, you will find plenty, but I always recommend this [article](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html) as a starting point!